# Convergence of the Product of Two Random Sequences

Tags: convergence, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

Suppose that there are two random i.i.d. sequences $\left\{X_n\right\}_{n=1}^N$ and $\left\{Y_t\right\}_{t=1}^T$. Assume finite moments $\mathrm{E}\left[X_n\right]$, $\mathrm{E}\left[X_n^2\right]$, $\mathrm{E}\left[Y_t\right]=0$ and $\mathrm{E}\left[Y_t^2\right]$. From CLT, $\sqrt{N}\left(\bar{X}_N-\mathrm{E}\left[X_n\right]\right)\overset{d}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{N}\left(0,\mathrm{E}\left[X_n^2\right]-\left(\mathrm{E}\left[X_n\right]\right)^2\right)$ and $\sqrt{T}\bar{Y}_T\overset{d}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{N}\left(0,\mathrm{E}\left[Y_t^2\right]\right)$. Can I infer anything about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{NT}}\sum_{n=1}^N{\sum_{t=1}^T{X_{n}Y_{t}}}$? I think I can exploit $\mathrm{E}\left[X_nY_t\right]=0$ and $\mathrm{Var}\left[X_nY_t\right]=\mathrm{E}\left[X_n^2\right]\mathrm{E}\left[Y_t^2\right]$, but I cannot apply Slutsky's Theorem since each converges in distribution, respectively.

Comment: Are the sequences independent?

Comment: Yes, they are independent.

Comment: It appears you are not considering the sum $X_1Y_1+X_2Y_2+...$ but rather $X_1\sum Y + X_2\sum Y +...$. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Correct. The sum you mentioned is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{X_iY_i}$, but now the sum is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}{X_iY_t}}$.